# Controlling learning rate decay or cyclic learning rate in Mathematica's neural nets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am using Mathematica's `NetTrain[]` function for training neural nets. There is a way to set the learning rate (`LearningRate` and `LearningRateMultiplier` options) but I want a decreasing learning rate or changes based on development of the loss.

Current call for transfer learning with fixed learning rate:

```
NetTrain[
  preTrainedNet, trainData, All, 
  ValidationSet -> valData, MaxTrainingRounds -> epochs, TargetDevice -> "GPU", 
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {
      "classifier" -> lr, 
      {"base", 1, "conv_conv2d"} -> lr, 
      {"base", 1, "conv_relu"} -> lr, 
       _ -> 0},
  BatchSize -> 8,
  TrainingProgressCheckpointing -> 
    {"Directory", "C:\\DataSets\\RZ-DL-Aug-Pre", "Interval" -> Quantity[10, "Rounds"]}
];
```

How can I implement what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the suboption `"LearningRateSchedule"` of the option `Method` helps? See the doc page of `NetTrain` > Options > Method. But I have to admit that the documentation is quite vague about the meaning of the function that can be fed to `"LearningRateSchedule"`.